# Python Word Search Solver

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I just don't know know where to begin. I've been given the question below and I'm really stuck. I would be very appreciative of any help. My attempt at coding is displayed below. Thanks.

"Write a function that accepts a 2-dimensional list of characters and a string (word) as input arguments. This function searches the rows of the 2d list to find a match for the word. If a match is found, this functions returns a list containing row index and column index of the start of the match, otherwise it returns the value None (no quotations).

```
characters=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'

function(crosswords,word)
```

Then your function should return [2,1].

Notice that the 2d input list represents a 2d crossword and the starting index of the horizontal word 'cat' is [2,1]

Comment: You said your attempt was below. All I see is code to set up actually starting your implementation. Also, you are calling a function called function that you have not shown. Is there more code you can show?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried and what errors or bugs you are getting. We are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: Also, you used `characters` as your matrix name, but tried calling `function(crosswords, word)`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting task... I'm at a fairly beginner level in Python so I can solve half your problem if you haven't done so already.

```
def function(crosswords, word):

for row in crosswords:
    join_list = "".join(row)
    if join_list.find(word) != -1:
        return [crosswords.index(row), row.index(word[0])]
else:
    return False
```

characters=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
print (function(characters, word))

This will return TRUE if the word is found in the array and FALSE if not. You will need to replace 'return True' and 'return False' with what you need to return.

**EDIT:** I worked out a solution, it gets the job done; though it may not be the best way to do this. There is probably room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords, word):

    list1=[]
    row_index = -1
    column_index = -1
    refind=''
    for row in crosswords:
        index=''
        for column in row:
            index= index+column
        list1.append(index)

    for find_word in list1:
        if word in find_word:
           row_index = list1.index(find_word)
           refind = find_word
           column_index = find_word.index(word)


    ret = [row_index,column_index]
    if row_index!= -1 and column_index != -1:
        return ret



crosswords=[['s','d','o','g'],['c','u','c','m'],['a','c','a','t'],['t','e','t','k']]
word='cat'
print(find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word))
```

Comment: You should prepend **every** line of your code with 4 spaces to indicate a code block for formatting purposes

Answer (score 0):

Hi how would it be different from to find word vertically instead of horizontally?
- The function searches the rows of the 2d list to find a match for the word.

Answer (score 0):

```python
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word):
    if not crosswords or not word:
        return None    
    number_of_rows=len(crosswords)
    for row_index in range (number_of_rows):
        temp_str=''
        for col_index in range(len(crosswords[0])):
            temp_str=temp_str+crosswords[row_index][col_index]
        if temp_str.find(word)>=0:
            return [row_index,temp_str.find(word)]
    return None
```

Comment: please explain your problem and tag the programming language in which above code is @sereno

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_word_horizontal(crosswords,word):
    if not crosswords or not word : # if empty then return None
        return None
    for index,row in enumerate(crosswords):
        temp_str=''.join(row)
        if temp_str.find(word)>=0:
            return [index,temp_str.find(word)]
    return None
```